# I'm trying to figure out how to make keyboard not hide the textfield

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:

```
class TextViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var chatTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SendButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChatField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var keyboardHeightLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var textView: UITextView! { return (view as! UITextView) }

    override func loadView() {
        let textView = UITextView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, textContainer: nil)
        textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        view = textView
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chatTextField.delegate = self
        NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TextViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let frameEnd = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeightEnd = view.convert(frameEnd, from: nil).size.height
       }





//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
{

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    ChatField.text=textField.text
      }
```

But the compiler shows:

> "Type TextViewController has no member keyboardWillShow"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Sorry guys but I did have a func called keyboardWillShow. I update the whole code so you guys can see.'
Thanks again

Comment: Certainly，you use the selector TextViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)， while it seems like  you should add ` func keyboardWillShow(textField: UITextField) -> Void { }` in TextViewController

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `keyboardWillShow` method to your class:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     // Add your logic here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add `TextViewController` while using selector `keyboardWillShow(_:)`. I ran your code with the following changes and it worked fine.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks it really helps

Comment: Kindly mark it as correct answer if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bilawal is right, adding the class-name as a prefix before the method indicates you want to call it as a class method, while you have declared it as an instance-method.

And also in the keyboardWillShow method you are not doing anything to make the textfield change it's frame depending on keyboard position/height.

Comment: Could you tell me what should I do in the keyboardWillShow? I corrected all the error but still not what I want